# Asp.net single instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, apache, mono, ihttphandler

I have a server running apache/mono.
I created few simple http handlers (*.ashx), that need to be accessed either directly from the browser (e.g. http://www.myserver.com/something.ashx?params) or via ssh tunnel (call will then look like http://localhost:port/something.ashx?params). Unique port is chosen when using ssh for each user.

The problem?
Each ssh connection seems to create another instance. Which wouldn't be a problem, if it didn't take so much time for mono to load and thus slowing down responses.

The easiest way out would be running the application in single instance.
Is this even possible and if so, how? 
Alternative approach would be majorly speeding up mono loading... and I'm not sure how.

Comment: Sounds like you need something to route the traffic to your ASP.NET instance, such as an Nginx or Apache reverse proxy.

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Comment: Using latest stable mono 5.14.0.177